# Example of non-unique-factorization in $\mathbb{Z}+x \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Could you provide me an example of a polynomial that is not uniquely factorized in $\mathbb{Z}+x \mathbb{Q}[x]$? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $x^2=(x/5)\cdot 5x$ and $x^2=x\cdot x$. The key point being $5x$ and $x$ aren't associates because $5$ is not a unit in $\mathbb Z +x\mathbb Q[x]$.